# Not able to enumerate items under RecentPlaces.lnk using IShellFolder::EnumObjects as displayed in Explorer

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, explorer, windows-shell

I am facing problem while enumerating and getting all items  under  "Recent Places" as displayed by explorer.
I tried as:

1. I get path of all the links ("Favorites")  for "Recent Places" it is "C:\Users\\Links\RecentPlaces.lnk".
2. SHCreateItemFromParsingName to get IShellItem
3. Check If it is a Link  IShellItem::GetAttributes and check against SFGAO_LINK
    For Link i get target ShellItem as:
    IShellItem::BindToHandler  passing BHID_LinkTargetItem.
4. Get IShellFolder from IShellItem using again  IShellItem::BindToHandler  passing BHID_SFObject
5. Enumerate IShellFolder 
   shellFolder->EnumObjects(NULL, SHCONTF_FOLDERS | SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, &enumIDList)
   enumIDList->Next(1, &childItemID, NULL)  << Here it returns S_FALSE in first iteration only.
   I am able to enumerate all other shellItems (All Libraries, Computer, Other Links like Desktop, Downloads etc. ) using the same approach. 
   But it is failing for  "Recent Places" link.
   please suggest what am i doing wrong here. OR any other approach which should work.
   Thanks in Advance.

EDIT:

```
HRESULT hr;
C_ComPtr<IShellItem> shellItem;
hr = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(TEXT("C:\Users\srvdsk\Links\RecentPlaces.lnk"), NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&shellItem));
if(S_OK != hr) return;
SFGAOF attrib;
shellItem->GetAttributes(SFGAO_FOLDER | SFGAO_LINK, &attrib);
if ( (attrib&SFGAO_LINK) ) {

    C_ComPtr<IShellItem> linkTargetShellItem;
    hr = shellItem->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_LinkTargetItem, IID_PPV_ARGS(&linkTargetShellItem));
    if (S_OK != hr) return;

    linkTargetShellItem->GetAttributes(SFGAO_FOLDER | SFGAO_LINK, &attrib);
    if ( (attrib&SFGAO_FOLDER) ) {        
        C_ComPtr<IShellFolder> shellFolder;
        hr = linkTargetShellItem->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_SFObject, IID_PPV_ARGS(&shellFolder));
        if (S_OK != hr) return;


        C_ComPtr<IEnumIDList> enumIDList;
        SHCONTF const flags = SHCONTF_FOLDERS | SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS;
        hr = shellFolder->EnumObjects(NULL, flags, &enumIDList);
        if (S_OK != hr) return;

        LPITEMIDLIST childItemID = NULL;
        while (S_OK == enumIDList->Next(1, &childItemID, NULL)) { //Next is returning S_FALSE in first iteration itself

            STRRET strRetItemName;
            hr = shellFolder->GetDisplayNameOf(childItemID, SHGDN_FORPARSING, &strRetItemName);
            if (S_OK != hr) return;            
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Algorithm is right. Show your code.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov , I have posted the code i used. Only for "Recent Places" link it is not working, it works for other links (Downloads, Desktop etc.) and Libraries Or ComputerFolder.

Answer (score 0):

In this place you get linkTargetShellItem:

```
shellItem->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_LinkTargetItem, IID_PPV_ARGS(&linkTargetShellItem));
```

But in this place you use old shellItem:

```
shellItem->BindToHandler(NULL, BHID_SFObject, IID_PPV_ARGS(&shellFolder));
```

You should you linkTargetShellItem instead of shellItem.

**Аlternative algorithm:**

```
procedure IterateLinkTarget(const AFileName: UnicodeString);
var
  ShellLink: IShellLinkW;
  PersistFile: IPersistFile;
  IDList: PItemIDList;
  Desktop: IShellFolder;
  Folder: IShellFolder;
  Enum: IEnumIDList;
  Child: PItemIDList;
  Fetched: DWORD;
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IShellLinkW, ShellLink));
  try
    OleCheck(ShellLink.QueryInterface(IPersistFile, PersistFile));
    try
      OleCheck(PersistFile.Load(PWideChar(AFileName), STGM_READ));
      OleCheck(ShellLink.GetIDList(IDList));
      try
        OleCheck(SHGetDesktopFolder(Desktop));
        try
          OleCheck(Desktop.BindToObject(IDList, nil, IShellFolder, Folder));
          try
            OleCheck(Folder.EnumObjects(0, SHCONTF_FOLDERS or SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, Enum));
            while Enum.Next(1, Child, Fetched) = S_OK do
              try

                // Process child here

              finally
                CoTaskMemFree(Child);
              end;
          finally
            Folder := nil;
          end;
        finally
          Desktop := nil;
        end;
      finally
        CoTaskMemFree(IDList);
      end;
    finally
      PersistFile := nil;
    end;
  finally
    ShellLink := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, It was typing mistake, In the original code its fine. As i said the code is working for other links ( Downloads, Desktop etc) only for Recent Places it is not working.

Comment: Do you see any problem with the code? why is it not working for Recent Places only and works for other links (Desktop, Downloads etc.) . Any suggestions?

Comment: I dont see any errors in your code but I cannot reproduce the problem you have. In the updated answer you can find alternative algorithm without using of IShellItem. May be it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I spent ages trying to figure this one out, and eventually found that it was my call to `CoInitializeEx(COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` that was the problem. The recent items folder only works with `COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED`. See this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287087).